# Making a resizable icon stick to the bottom of a dynamically sized div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resize

I am trying to work on a div with that is populated by information on mouseover.

The div it is populated to is both resizable and draggable, and that works just fine. My minor issue is that the resizable icon stays in its place when the box flexes.

I would like to see if I can make the resizable icon remain on the bottom of the div as it grows in size?

```js
$(".btn").mouseenter(function() {
  $("#thepoem").html($(this).val());

});
$(".btn").mouseleave(function() {
  $("#thepoem").empty();
});

$("#superresizablediv").resizable();
$("#superresizablediv").draggable();
```

```css
#superresizablediv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 5%;
  min-width: 250px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: #5fc0e3;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 1
}

#thepoem {
  display: flex;
  display: inherit;
  min-height: 50px;
  min-width: 250px;
  background-color: #5fc0e3;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<button class="btn" value="Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary, Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore— While I nodded, nearly napping, suddenly there came a tapping, As of some one gently rapping, rapping at my chamber door. “’Tis some
      visitor,” I muttered, “tapping at my chamber door— Only this and nothing more.">The raven verse 1</button>
<button class="btn" value="Ah, distinctly I remember it was in the bleak December;
And each separate dying ember wrought its ghost upon the floor.
    Eagerly I wished the morrow;—vainly I had sought to borrow
    From my books surcease of sorrow—sorrow for the lost Lenore—
For the rare and radiant maiden whom the angels name Lenore—
            Nameless here for evermore.">The raven verse 2</button>
<div id="superresizablediv" class="ui-resizable-se">
  <div id="thepoem"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the height of `#superresizablediv` on mouseenter and reset the height on mouseleave

```js
var height = '';

$(".btn").mouseenter(function() {
  height = $("#superresizablediv").outerHeight();
  $("#thepoem").html($(this).val());
  $("#superresizablediv").height($("#thepoem").outerHeight())

});
$(".btn").mouseleave(function() {
  $("#thepoem").empty();
  $("#superresizablediv").height(height)
});

$("#superresizablediv").resizable();
$("#superresizablediv").draggable();
```

```css
#superresizablediv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 5%;
  min-width: 250px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: #5fc0e3;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 1
}

#thepoem {
  display: flex;
  display: inherit;
  min-height: 50px;
  min-width: 250px;
  background-color: #5fc0e3;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<button class="btn" value="Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary, Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore— While I nodded, nearly napping, suddenly there came a tapping, As of some one gently rapping, rapping at my chamber door. “’Tis some
      visitor,” I muttered, “tapping at my chamber door— Only this and nothing more.">The raven verse 1</button>
<button class="btn" value="Ah, distinctly I remember it was in the bleak December;
And each separate dying ember wrought its ghost upon the floor.
    Eagerly I wished the morrow;—vainly I had sought to borrow
    From my books surcease of sorrow—sorrow for the lost Lenore—
For the rare and radiant maiden whom the angels name Lenore—
            Nameless here for evermore.">The raven verse 2</button>
<div id="superresizablediv" class="ui-resizable-se">
  <div id="thepoem"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. I accepted your answer! It caused a bit of another unexpected issue that the div will of course return to the original size `$("#superresizablediv").height(height)`, now I'm trying to figure out if I resize the box height, it would set the min height to not be shorter than where I dragged it to. The width will not shrink, but the height will. Tips?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve. Currently the box will return the to height - even if resized - it was before the text was populated.

Comment: Yeah it's a bit complex. The idea is that the box can be resized by clicking and dragging the handle, but when the box empties, it reverts back to the min-height attribute. I'm wondering, by manually dragging the resize handle to a new height, let's say 500px, it would set the css so the box would not shrink below 500px until I drag it again